# Get Surrounding Pincode by passing argument as one pincode

Tags: pin-code

How to get surronding pincodes by passing argument as pincode in java?

Comment: Please provide a code stub and example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have some set of pincodes and their coordinates list in my database and end user, enter one pincode then I need to bring pincodes (which are there in my db) based on that code pincode within 20 km range.Thank you

Comment: And I would like to ask you that how can i get a pincode coordinates through java (or) is there any api for this one.